# ASC 122U NFC Reader compatible with EMV Contactless Cards

Tags: emv, contactless-smartcard, acr122

I am trying to read a EMV card using an APDU Command, however it seems the ACR122U external reader is blocking the APDU Command.

Select Command:

```
APDU-C -> 00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 0E
APDU-R <- Error no response
```

Is it possible that the ACR122U reader is blocking the command ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to SELECT FILE 1PAY.SYS.DDF01,
"Payment System Environment (PSE)"
To get the PSE directory and the card should response with Application Identifier (AID). but you set the LE=0E replace it to "00" .

Corrected APDU =>
PPSE = '00 a4 04 00 0e 32 50 41 59 2e 53 59 53 2e 44 44 46 30 31 00'

if The selection failed then the ADF doesn't exist (SW1/SW2=6A82)

if the selection is true then Application Identifier (AID) start command
Possible AID's:

A0000000031010

A0000000032020

A0000000041010

A0000000043060

AIDPrefix ='00 a4 04 00 07'